# Android, access System private/public certificates

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

Android System has a builtin certificate Store. The certificates from this store are for example used when making an Exchange Account or setting up a wireless LAN.

This there some way to use the certificates in my own application? I would prefer this to managing my own certificate store. An Android 4.0+ solution is acceptable for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 4.0+ is what you'll need though:

Using [KeyChain](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html)

Here's the [original blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/03/unifying-key-store-access-in-ics.html)

*Excerpt*:

> **New in ICS: KeyChain**
>
> To bridge the gap in ICS, there’s a new API named [KeyChain](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html) that
>   regulates application access to the system key store and allows users
>   to grant application access to the credentials stored there.
>   Additionally, this API enables applications to initiate installation
>   of credentials from X.509 certificates and PKCS#12 key stores.

Comment: I am using another 4.0+ feature (VPN), so that is no problem :). Thanks for the fast answer