# Xamarin forms android using user certificates

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, keychain

If a user has installed a pfx user certificate on an Android device, chrome browser sees and asks permission to use users client certificate to access a server that accepts such certificates.
**What is the Xamarin forms equivalent ?**

[image: certificate access / selection]

How can we access these certificates in Xamarin form apps for Android.

Under windows (UWP) Accessing  user certificates is just

```
              httpClientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;
              httpClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Under Android we are trying to use Custom version AndroidClienthandler

```
 MyAndroidClientHandler clientHandler = new MyAndroidClientHandler();
```

**In a Custom AndroidClientHandler There are 2 problems to solve**
1) how to get a certificate from the users certificates from the keychain ?
 Something like this post perhaps?  [Client Certificates on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20324240/1347784)

2) How do you add that cert to the ClientHandler?
   Can I simply do this
            clientHandler.TrustedCerts.Add(cert);
or  more likely
    [Add certificate to SSL Context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55060975/1347784)

Has anyone ever managed to do a HTTPS call using an already installed client certificate from Xamarin forms ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Android didn't provide a direct way to use a default credential, but Android provide developers with some choice to [use system-wide credentials or app's private credential](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#WhichShouldIUse).

KeyChain may help to launch a system dialog for user to choose a certificate/enter the password. Refering to [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047828/android-access-system-private-public-certificates).

And extend AndroidClientHandler as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951913/xamarin-android-adding-client-certificate) is what I found to use the client certificate.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx Nicole Ill take a look at the links to see if I can figure something out from them. Its mainly  Android docu and JAVA blog post. I was hoping someone has managed to the equivalent in Xamarin forms.  It is of course in the right direction.

Comment: ok not really  the solution i was hoping for, but its closer than no tip at all. Thanks Nicole.